# Is there a way to make @PersistenceContext flexible?

Tags: java, variables, persistence

I guess the question is pretty simple. I have no ideas how to do it, my only guess what this one:

```
@PersistenceContext("Bibliothouris" + RunParallelized.thread)
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

Thread is a static variable in the RunParallelized class. But the annotation can't be variable. It would fix all my problems though.

I have declared this in my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="Bibliothouris1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" />
<persistence-unit name="Bibliothouris2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" />
<persistence-unit name="Bibliothouris3" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" />
<persistence-unit name="Bibliothouris4" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" />
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

This can't work, unfortunately. Only compile-time constants are allowed as parameters for Annotations. The reason is that [annotation processing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/) can run in a separate cycle before the classes are compiled. So an annotation-based solution can't work for you, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it might help you,

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/objectstate.html